# Angular2+Spring Security CORS и CSRF

Tags: typescript, angular2, spring-security, spring-boot

Есть два сервера на первом стоит angular url: `http://localhost:4200`, на втором tomcat с Spring Boot url: `http:localhost:8080`.

При попытке отправить `POST` запрос браузер пишет

```
Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника
запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://localhost:8080/.
(Причина:    отсутствует заголовок CORS «Access-Control-Allow-Origin»).
```

Логи `Tomcat`

```
2016-12-02 06:51:10.134 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing OPTIONS request for [/]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.136 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
2016-12-02 06:51:10.140 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public void org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$EmptyHandler.handle()]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.149 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
2016-12-02 06:51:10.149 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
2016-12-02 06:51:10.149 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.150 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally
2016-12-02 06:51:10.150 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@329e259c
2016-12-02 06:51:10.150 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-02 06:51:10.150 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-12-02 06:51:10.150 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5dd5a01e
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Bound request context to thread: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5dd5a01e
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/css/**'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/js/**'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/images/**'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/webjars/**'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/**/favicon.ico'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/error'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.159 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.167 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:8080/
2016-12-02 06:51:10.167 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@329e259c
2016-12-02 06:51:10.167 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2016-12-02 06:51:10.167 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2016-12-02 06:51:10.167 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.w.f.OrderedRequestContextFilter    : Cleared thread-bound request context: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@5dd5a01e
2016-12-02 06:51:10.170 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/error]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.170 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
2016-12-02 06:51:10.171 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.171 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'basicErrorController'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.181 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in [refresh] with type [String]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.185 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.c.e.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver  : Found key 'spring.template.provider.cache' in [refresh] with type [String]
2016-12-02 06:51:10.190 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
2016-12-02 06:51:10.190 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'error'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.192 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'error'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.192 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@1fba2013] based on requested media type 'text/html'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.192 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@1fba2013] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-12-02 06:51:10.197 DEBUG 8380 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Если потребуется еще какая либо инфрмация, готов ее предоставить.

---

**UPDATE 1**

CORS получилось настроить в конвиге следующим образом:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfigure extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addMapping("/**")
                    .allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

Проблему с CSRF можно частично решить его отключенимем, но мне все же кажется что это не самый лучший вариант.
Мне удалось натсроить спринг так что бы сессии сохранялись в таблицу которую spring автоматически создает и этой сессии приваивался csrf-токен который так же сохраняется в таблицу, но на клиент отправляется только заголовок о добавлении cookie с id сессии, а csrf-токен никуда не отпраляется.
Вот что приходит от сервера при очищеных cookie:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Language: ru-RU
Content-Length: 362
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date: Sat, 24 Dec 2016 20:11:44 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: SESSION=7b4d0509-4cfb-40e0-9484-72abcdfe2375;path=/;Secure;HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
Vary: Origin
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
access-control-allow-credentials: true
```

Вот что посылает клиент при следующем запросе:

```
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0)   Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/registration
Content-Length: 69
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cookie: SESSION=7b4d0509-4cfb-40e0-9484-72abcdfe2375
DNT: 1
Connection: keep-alive
```

Стоит ли расширять класс `HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` что бы токен не только сохранятся в базу но и отправлялся клиенту для сохранения, или другой способ это сделять?

Comment: Ошибка говорит, что кросдоменные запросы не разрешены на сервере. Попробуйте их разрешить глобально как указано на сайте [спринга](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) , где укажите `allowedOrigins("*")`, либо вместо `"*"` хост откуда идут запросы

Comment: @MrFylypenko Спасибо, проблема с cors пропала, но теперь spring ругается на отсутствие CSSF. Гуглил этот вопрос, но как конкретно это сделать для angular2 не нашел.

Comment: В принципе со стороны spring можно все настроить, и оно будет правильно работать. Но затем, если вы используете новый HttpClient, вы столкнетесь с вот этой проблемой: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18859

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка говорит, что кросдоменные запросы не разрешены на сервере. Попробуйте их разрешить глобально как указано на сайте [спринга](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/) , где укажите `allowedOrigins("*")`, либо вместо "*" хост откуда идут запросы.

Так же Вы имели ввиду скорее всего CSRF. В spring security 4 и выше эта функция включена по умолчанию, ее необходимо отключить, либо использовать. Для отключения этой функции вызвите у объекта `HttpSecurity`  методы `.csrf().disable()`, вот пример как это сделать:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()  //дополнил .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            //другие вызовы
    }       
}
```

Далее после этого настройте в ангулар2 параметр `withCredentials = true;`, в ангулар1 это делается так: `$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;`, либо делайте запросы с этим параметром, например:

```
http.get('http://my.domain.com/request', { withCredentials: true })...
```

Без настройки этого параметра, при каждом кроссдоменном запросе будет создаваться новая сессия, и spring security работать не будет.

Comment: Насколько я понял Angular 2 не отпровляет csrf токен на сервер, Spring видит что токена нет и кидает в ответку html с ошибкой. Я уже перепробовал все способы которые смог найти в гугле. Jстановился на том что, выключил проверку csrf, надеюсь смогу решить эту проблему когда скилл подкачаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вам стоит посмотреть сюда: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html

Angular's http has built-in support for the client-side half of this technique in its XSRFStrategy. The default CookieXSRFStrategy is turned on automatically. Before sending an HTTP request, the CookieXSRFStrategy looks for a cookie called XSRF-TOKEN and sets a header named X-XSRF-TOKEN with the value of that cookie.

The server must do its part by setting the initial XSRF-TOKEN cookie and confirming that each subsequent state-modifying request includes a matching XSRF-TOKEN cookie and X-XSRF-TOKEN header.

XSRF/CSRF tokens should be unique per user and session, have a large random value generated by a cryptographically secure random number generator, and should expire in a day or two

Стыкуем с http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-cookie настройкой

Либо возможно потребуется 
Your server may use a different cookie or header name for this purpose. An Angular application can customize cookie and header names by providing its own CookieXSRFStrategy values.

```
{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN') }
```

Comment: Добавил `{ provide: XSRFStrategy, useValue: new CookieXSRFStrategy('XSRF-TOKEN', 'X-XSRF-TOKEN') }` в `app.module.ts` и в header запроса `this.headers.append('XSRF-TOKEN','X-XSRF-TOKEN');`, но при отправке POST запроса все еще возникает 403 ошибка. Знаю что делаю что то не так, но не могу понять что.

Comment: Покажите как выглядят загловки XHR в Network