# Авторизация Angular 2 в Spring boot security

Tags: angular2, spring-security

В целях обучения делаю приложение, в роли клиента Angular 2 на бэкенде Spring boot, находятся на разынх серверах. На данный момент сделал регистрацию пользователя с автологином, но после регистрации возвращается только `anonymousUser`. В качестве способа авторизации я выбрал авторизацию по токену. Если делать такую авторизацию через JSP все работает, а через SPA не хватает знаний как это реализвать и примеров в сети нормальных не найти.

Надеюсь на подсказку что нужно еще добавить для авторизации.

[Front end](https://github.com/Bleser92/frontend-spring-angular2-sci-lvl-4)
[Back end](https://github.com/Bleser92/backend-spring-angular2-sci-lvl-4)

---

**UPDATE 1**
Исправил косяк с тем что `SecurityServiceImpl` нигде не использовался. Теперь в базе сохраняется сессия и вроде как авторизация прошла, но `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails()` возвращает `null`.

Comment: Проверьте куки которые отправляются от фронта к бэку, они действительно отправляются одни и те же, или с каждым запросом разные? Параметр у ангулара withCredentials=trueвключен, как в указано  [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/598939/218319)?

Comment: @MrFylypenko withCredentials=true когда отправляю post запросс на регистрацию. Куки вообще никакие не приходят, только в заголовке ответа есть id сессии.

Comment: При кросдоменных запросах всегда нужно отправлять `withCredentials=true`, без него авторизация не работает.

Comment: @MrFylypenko Я отпровлял только POST запросы значит `withCredentials` всегда был равен `true` это можно увидеть здесь на 18 строке  https://github.com/Bleser92/frontend-spring-angular2-sci-lvl-4/blob/master/src/app/service/registration.service.ts

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете как работает `withCredentials`, можете почитать [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain#запросы-от-имени-пользователя). Т.е. при запросе без этого параметра(при кроссдоменных запросах) сервер НИКОГДА не узнает что это текущий юзер и всегда его будет видеть как новый и на каждый запрос будет открывать новую сессию. В вашем примере на гитхабе фрон отправляет пост запрос на регистрацию с этим параметром, а в юзер-сервисе гет запрос без него, поэтому получение пользователя всегда будет нул или аноним.

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо попробую сделать как вы сказали. Я не так давно начал учить веб много не знаю.